# Integer solutions to hyperplanes intersections

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-number-theory

I am interested in a set of k linearly independent hyperplanes in $\mathbb{R}^n$:

$  a_{k,1} x_1 +…+ a_{k,n} x_n = c_k $

With all the $a_i$ and $c_j$ integers.
I also assume $k<n$, hence solutions are guaranteed to exist.

My interest lies in the existence of integer solutions.

There are specific cases where it is easy to prove the absence of solution:

*Example, for a fixed* $k$, *if* $\gcd \left( a_{k,i} \right)_{i=1,\dots n} $ *does not divide* $c_k$, *there cannot be any solution.*

Besides this arithmetic approach, is there another method to determine the existence of integer solutions?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reformulate your question, you want to solve $AX=C$, where $A\in M_{k\times n}(\mathbb{Z}), $X\in\mathbb{Z}^n$ and $C\in\mathbb{Z}^k$.

The key tool is "Smith normal form" (one could use the Hermite normal form, but whatever). Since there are plenty of documentation everywhere on the web, i will only sketch the method.

Since the rows are of $A$ are linearly independent, one may show that there exist two matrices $U\in GL_k(\mathbb{Z}),V\in GL_n(\mathbb{Z})$ (that is, invertible integral matrices whose inverse is an integral matrix. This is equivalent to ask the determinant to be $\pm 1$)

such that $UAV=(D\mid 0_{k\times n-k})$, where $D=\begin{pmatrix} d_1 & & \cr & \ddots & \cr & & d_k\end{pmatrix} $ is a diagonal $k\times k$ matrix, where $1\leq d_1\mid d_2\cdots\mid d_k$.

Set $X'=V^{-1}X=\begin{pmatrix} x'_1\cr \vdots\cr x'_n\end{pmatrix}$ and $C'=UC=\begin{pmatrix} c'_1\cr \vdots\cr c'_k\end{pmatrix}.$

Then the original system of equations is equivalent to $d_ix'_i=c'_i$, $i=1,\ldots,k$.

Hence, there is a solution if and only if $d_i\mid c'_i$ for all $i=1,\ldots,k$. I let you write up the set of solutions of the original system.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly the kind of approach I was looking for!